Randomize selection of follower via uipath
I want to open a predefined account and follow randomly chosen accounts from the follower list of this specific account. E.g. open the account "xyz" go to the follower section and randomly follow accounts in the list. It should skip account it is following. Is that possible or is the randomize selection of an account not possible?
Thanks

UiPath itself doesn't have a built-in activity specifically for randomly selecting items from a list. But you can achieve randomness through programming constructs. For instance, you can generate a random index within the range of the follower list and then select the account at that index. Here is how to approach it:

Start by using UiPath's activities to navigate to the desired social media and log into your account.
Then you should be able to navigate to the followers list of the account you want to do this for.
Then you can use UiPath to scroll through the list and collect the needed information to extract the followers' list(for example you'd probably need the usernames).
After you've created your list you can achieve randomness by generating a random number within the range of the follower count and then selecting that username.
Then you can check if the account is already being followed and if it's not followed you can use UiPath to follow the account.
And then you can loop the process to repeat it as many times as you want.

